# Apache2 not listening on any port other than 80

Tags: ubuntu

When I run apache on port 80 it works fine. But if I change the port then it's accepting connection from localhost only. Somebody please help me figure out what is the problem.

My iptables -L result

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1032

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: Show a `iptables -L`

Comment: Show us your Listen statement(s).

Comment: @lainNameVirtualHost *:1032
Listen 1032
Inside my /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Comment: If i change  1032 to 80 inside my /etc/apache2/ports.conf and /etc/apache2/sites-available/default then it works smooth..

Comment: Are you running on a server infrastructure that you manage yourself, or a VPS/dedicated server hosted by someone else for you?

Comment: @jgoldschrafe Im trying to configure it on Amazon EC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Amazon EC2, your instance has a security group attached that functions as an external firewall. If you view your instance properties through the AWS console, you should be able to easily determine which security group is in effect on your node. You'll need to add a firewall exclusion in that security group (see "Security Groups" under "Network & Security" in the left-hand navigation bar) in order to allow access to that port from outside the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to first flush the firewall rules as follows:

```
iptables -F
```

And if that doesn't work, try disabling Ubuntu's uncomplicated firewall:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: Thanks for your  response..
I have tried both and still the same.